# Receiving the error "An invalid PHP type for parameter 1 was specified" when using a parameterised query

Tags: php, sql-server, sqlsrv

I am trying to execute a stored procedure which inputs data to my database.

I am setting up my parameters as follows:

(`$conn` has my db creds, `$xml` contains data from an XML file)

```php
$params = array(
    array($xml->filenumber, SQLSRV_PARAM_IN, SQLSRV_SQLTYPE_VARCHAR(20)),
    array($xml->lastName, SQLSRV_PARAM_IN, SQLSRV_SQLTYPE_VARCHAR(25)),
    array($xml->firstName, SQLSRV_PARAM_IN, SQLSRV_SQLTYPE_VARCHAR(25)),
    array("",  SQLSRV_PARAM_OUT, SQLSRV_PHPTYPE_STRING(14))
);
```

The datatypes correspond with the stored procedure:

```sql
@FileNumber varchar(20),
@FamilyName varchar(25),
@GivenName  varchar(25), 
@FileID     varchar(14) output
```

And then executing it in PHP :

```
$sql = "EXEC dbo.AddFileHdr @FileNumber = ?, @FamilyName = ?, @GivenName = ?, @FileID =?";
$stmt = sqlsrv_prepare($conn, $sql, $params);
if( !$stmt ) {
 die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
if(sqlsrv_execute($stmt)){
    while($res = sqlsrv_next_result($stmt)){
//doesnt need to output anything here
    }
  }else{
    die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
  }
```

Expected behavior is for the query to return a 14 character varchar `FileID` after I insert the 3 fields. I have tested the stored procedure in SQL Server Management Studio and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

`SQLSRV_PHPTYPE_STRING` accepts an encoding type constant as parameter:

```php
$fileId = "";

$params = array(
    array($xml->filenumber, SQLSRV_PARAM_IN, SQLSRV_SQLTYPE_VARCHAR(20)),
    array($xml->lastName, SQLSRV_PARAM_IN, SQLSRV_SQLTYPE_VARCHAR(25)),
    array($xml->firstName, SQLSRV_PARAM_IN, SQLSRV_SQLTYPE_VARCHAR(25)),
    array(&$fileId,  SQLSRV_PARAM_OUT, SQLSRV_PHPTYPE_STRING(SQLSRV_ENC_CHAR))
);
```

You can change `SQLSRV_ENC_CHAR` with other encoding constants as stated here: https://www.php.net/manual/en/sqlsrv.constants.php

By the way, i suggest you to always use variables for your query parameters and pass it by reference (see `$fileId`):

> Variables passed as query parameters should be passed by reference instead of by value. For example, pass &$myVariable instead of $myVariable. A PHP warning is raised when a query with by-value parameters is executed.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the issue was because I was not passing a string to the parameter with `$xml->child`

This was solved by casting the xml data as a string e.g.: `$param2 = (string)$xml->lastName;`